# How to normalize skewed data before clustering?

Tags: clustering, normalization, skewness

My question deals with what is the right way to normalize my data. My data consists 6 features, all together representing a state in an environment for reinforcement learning. My goal is to cluster states with KMeans, so of course I need to normalize values first.

Below are histograms of the different features:
[image: Feature1 distribution]
[image: Feature2 distribution]
[image: Feature4 distribution]
[image: Feature6 distribution]

(X axis is feature value, Y axis is number of appearances. if you wonder where are features 3 and 5, they are kinda look like normal)

I wonder what is the right way to normalize each feature (or all of them together) to use kmeans.

I tried to apply f-score (all features toghther, not one by one) but I wonder if it is the right away. The minimum value I get is -4.6 (in feature 2, as you can see it has values around zero) with maximum of around ~1. Are there better suggestions what can I do?

Comment: `so of course I need to normalize values first` Why? K-means itself requires no pre-processing. It may be good or even necessary, but then the question is why? Put forward the reason. Also, what are the f-scores?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can follow:

1. Box-cox transform
2. Log transform
3. Square root transform

For detailed explanation you can follow this link
https://towardsdatascience.com/top-3-methods-for-handling-skewed-data-1334e0debf45

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The k-means algorithm is not guaranteed to converge to a global optimum and is very initialization dependent; furthermore, its objective of squared Euclidean distance results in it minimizing intra-cluster variance. This means for k-means, you generally want your covariance matrix to be spherical; i.e. the covariance matrix is proportional to the identity matrix.

This means techniques like z-score scaling or range normalization on each feature can be useful. To see why, try coming up with a 2D example of where k-means changes depending on the initialization -- it's a common exam question that I've gotten that lends more insight into the behavior of k-means.

Obviously, it's hard (impossible, even) to visualize things in 6 dimensions, but if you can't plot out your data to analyze it yourself, I'd recommend asking yourself -- why k-means as opposed to any other clustering algorithm?

Here's a link with more info on the assumptions of [k-means clustering](http://varianceexplained.org/r/kmeans-free-lunch/) that I find useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but it is not a solution for my problem. For many other clustering algorithms as well I'll need to normalize my data. And I'm still not sure how to normalize it